# How to get Parent element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the parent element of `cartError` so I can access the particular cart-item-details where the cart-item-size and `itm-quantity` is... because I'm looping through the cart to if a new cart item is added with the same size increase quantity from 1 to 2

```js
    var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('side-cart-   items')[0]
    var cartItemSizes = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-size")
    for(var i=0; i < cartItemSizes.length;i++){
        cartError=cartItemSizes[i]
        if(cartError.innerText== size){
           var cartItem = cartError.parentElement
           var cartQuantity = cartError.getElementsByClassName('itm-quantity')
           console.log(cartQuantity.innerText)
           return
        }     
    }
```

```html
<div class="section side-cart-items">
                <div class="side-cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item-image">
                        <img src="./images/product/SASSI-HOLFORD-RTW-SS21-AQUAREMARINE-PEARL-DUNSTER-TOP-DUNSTER-SHORTS-2-1154x1600.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item column">
                        <div class="cart-item-details">
                            <h2>Dunster Shorts</h2>
                            <p>size <span class="cart-item-size">36</span></p>
                            <p><span class="itm-quantity">1 </span>&times;<span class="itm-price">$285.00</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="cart-item-remove">[ REMOVE ]</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="side-cart-item">
                    <div class="cart-item-image">
                        <img src="./images/product/SASSI-HOLFORD-RTW-SS21-AQUAREMARINE-PEARL-DUNSTER-TOP-DUNSTER-SHORTS-2-1154x1600.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart-item column">
                        <div class="cart-item-details">
                            <h2>Dunster Shorts</h2>
                            <p>size <span class="cart-item-size">40</span></p>
                            <p><span class="itm-quantity">1</span> &times;<span class="itm-price">$200.00</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="cart-item-remove">[ REMOVE ]</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is `size`? where do you define it?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Size is a variable that contains the text in cart-item-size...Size is defined above... this is just a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that parent element of `cartError` is `p` tag not `cart-item-details`. Actually   you need to use `cartError.parentElement.parentElement` to access the `cart-item-details` and then use `cartItem.getElementsByClassName('itm-quantity');` to access the all `itm-quantity` tags:

```js
 var size = "36";

 var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('side-cart-items')[0]
 var cartItemSizes = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-size");
 for (var i = 0; i < cartItemSizes.length; i++) {
     cartError = cartItemSizes[i]
     if (cartError.innerText == size) {
         var cartItem = cartError.parentElement.parentElement
         var cartQuantity = cartItem.getElementsByClassName('itm-quantity');

         for (let item of cartQuantity) {
             console.log(item.innerText);
         }
     }
 }
```

```html
<div class="section side-cart-items">
    <div class="side-cart-item">
        <div class="cart-item-image">
            <img src="./images/product/SASSI-HOLFORD-RTW-SS21-AQUAREMARINE-PEARL-DUNSTER-TOP-DUNSTER-SHORTS-2-1154x1600.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item column">
            <div class="cart-item-details">
                <h2>Dunster Shorts</h2>
                <p>size <span class="cart-item-size">36</span></p>
                <p><span class="itm-quantity">1 </span>&times;<span class="itm-price">$285.00</span></p>
            </div>
            <button class="cart-item-remove">[ REMOVE ]</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-cart-item">
        <div class="cart-item-image">
            <img src="./images/product/SASSI-HOLFORD-RTW-SS21-AQUAREMARINE-PEARL-DUNSTER-TOP-DUNSTER-SHORTS-2-1154x1600.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item column">
            <div class="cart-item-details">
                <h2>Dunster Shorts</h2>
                <p>size <span class="cart-item-size">40</span></p>
                <p><span class="itm-quantity">1</span> &times;<span class="itm-price">$200.00</span></p>
            </div>
            <button class="cart-item-remove">[ REMOVE ]</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JosephSmart Is this what you want? Actually it is not clear for me what exactly you want. I just see some error in your code and I fixed them. let me know if expect other result

Comment: Thanks man... everything is working well.. I wastoo tired to spot those mistakes

Comment: Instead of counting the number parents, use `cartError.closest(".cart-item-details")`

Comment: @Barmar Excellent. Yes it is good idea use `cartError.closest(".cart-item-details")` instead of multiple parent Element